# fullPage.js scroll Skipping Slides

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I'm using fullPage.js and am running into issues with my top navigation. I have the code below which works, but skips slides 2-3 when scrolling with a trackpad, but with arrow keys will skip 2 on the way down and 3 on the way up. Thanks.

```
<div id="fullpage">

        <div class="section this-is-home"data-anchor="firstPage">
            <div class="slide-one-container">
                <h4>TESTING</h4>
                <p>content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="section this-is-jam" data-anchor="secondPage">Test2</div>
        <div class="section" data-anchor="thirdPage">Test4</div>
        <div class="section" data-anchor="fourthPage"></div>
</div>




<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //Navigation
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage', 'fourthPage'],
        menu: '#myMenu'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Definitely you are doing something wrong. Your markup and initialization works as expected as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/496/

The error is somewhere else. Make sure you dont initialize the plugin multiple times. (which is a very common error in people using ajax techniques such as the ones used by Rails framework)

Comment: Hi @Alvaro, the site is just static and I believe I'm only calling it once. I'm testing it live here: http://thisisjust.in/ . Any other ideas what it might be? I can get it to go one slide at a time using the scrollwheel on my mouse, but still no luck with the arrow keys or trackpad.

Comment: Yeah, you are running it twice... in main.js and in the HTML file. I will add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you dont initialize the plugin multiple times. (which is a very common error in people using ajax techniques such as the ones used by Rails framework)

You are calling fullPage.js twice... in main.js and in the HTML file.